# How can I determine if an HTML element has a value, even if it is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that can exist as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="simple_search_criteria" id="simple_search_criteria" value="" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="simple_search_criteria" id="simple_search_criteria"/>
```

and my code needs to know whether the value exists and what the value is.  I have code that works below, but feels kludgy since I'm doing two calls on the element, any suggestions on improving the code below?

```
if ($('#simple_search_criteria').attr('value') !== undefined) {
  var searchCriteria = $('#simple_search_criteria').val();
  // Do stuff with searchCriteria, even if it is an empty string
}
```

I like the code below but it doesn't work since `.val()` returns an empty string in both situations...

```
var searchCriteria = $('#simple_search_criteria').val();
if (searchCriteria) {
  // do stuff with searchCriteria
}
```

Any improvements would be appreciated, I'm always trying to improve my js!

Comment: can't you just check against the count of the length of the string?

Comment: You said both cases return empty string from `val()`.  That's all that matters, right?  In both cases a value is not set.  It doesn't matter if it is blank or doesn't exist.  Both are "not set"

Comment: I think he can't because `$().val().length` returns 0 if there is no `value` attribute.

Comment: But that case would be the "not set" case.  If he only wants to do logic if a value is set, it doesn't matter how it is not set.  Just that it is not set.  He's not trying to do one branch of logic if it is blank, vs another if it is undefined.

Comment: document.getElementById("simple_search_criteria").hasAttribute("value"); is for checking if the attribute exists. the code in the example is correct for checking if the attribute has a value.

Comment: you can do like this `var val = $('#simple_search_criteria').attr('value') || ""` and check if `val  == ""` as it always return the value if exists

Answer (score 3):

It would be faster to use regular JavaScript. Try [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```
var searchCriteria = document.getElementById('simple_search_criteria').hasAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to check that val() returns anything and if so check if what is there is not empty.

To respond to a comment (that was deleted), typeof will return 'undefined' if for example the element (which corresponds here to `$('#simple_search_criteria')`) does not exist. Documentation for typeof can he also useful. You may have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```
var searchCriteria = $('#simple_search_criteria').val();
if (typeof(searchCriteria) !== 'undefined' and searchCriteria.length > 0) {
// do stuff with searchCriteria
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sorin87bv, but that won't work since I want to do something with the value if it is empty (length == 0)

Comment: Then why not split what I added there in two: first check  typeof(searchCriteria)  !== 'undefined' then inside do the check for length == 0 and do what you need else 'do something else'. This way you have 3 cases (when the variable is undefined, when the string is empty and when string is not empty so you can act accordingly to each of them)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a jquery helper for checking the existance of an attribute but javascript has the method hasAttribute natively.

```
document.getElementById("simple_search_criteria").hasAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use the `typeof` attribute to distinguish between undefined and the empty string in this case:

```
typeof(document.getElementById("simple_search_criteria"))==='string';
```

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 1):

An `input` element always has a value, even if its `value` attribute is omitted in the markup, which is why `.val()` doesn't distinguish between the presence of the attribute with an empty value, and the absence of the attribute. Critically, **your form will submit with the same `simple_search_criteria=` (empty string) data** in both cases, so the server receiving the form submission will not be able to distinguish the two. This is something you'll need to keep in mind when designing your form. If you want to omit this parameter you need to omit this particular `input` element altogether, not just its `value` attribute.

Nevertheless, if you want your application to behave based on the presence or absence of the attribute you need to check that directly. You can save some overhead by caching the selector in a separate variable:

```
var searchCriteriaInput = $('#simple_search_criteria');
if (searchCriteriaInput.attr('value') !== undefined) {
  var searchCriteria = searchCriteriaInput.val();
  // Do stuff with searchCriteria, even if it is an empty string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried that but it still doesn't feel super clean.  Definitely a solution though!